# Laravel custom authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I'm starting to discover Laravel 5, so I might need a bit of your help to understand a few things.

First, I want to develop a login page. It seems that Laravel has a whole authentication system, and I guess I should use it.

Nevertheless, I want to display a login page (I know how to do this!), but after this, I would like to send the credentials to a server via an API call. The server will then tell me if the user is allowed to log in or not.

As far I understand Laravel and authentication, it seems that the authentication system works only with a local DB.

Can you confirm I need to use a custom authentication driver to do this? 
I've been following [this solution](http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5)
but I get this error when loading my page:

```
FatalErrorException in CustomUserProvider.php line 6:
Interface 'Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface' not found
```

Any help would be appreciated, feel free to ask me for more information if you need it.

Thanks

Comment: You do need to use a custom authentication driver. I think in the the current version of Laravel 5 the interface is `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried following the same thread you mentioned and arrived at the very same results. Then I checked the implementation of native UserProviders (Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider and Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider) and ended up using the same set as in EloquentUserProvider:

```
<?php namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class MyUserProvider implements UserProvider {
   // Implementation goes here
}
```

I believe this to be more correct approach as the suggestions from the forum thread seem to be possibly for an older/beta version of L5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my CustomUserProvider file:

```
<?php namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as UserProviderInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
```

It's now working :-)